# Polymorphic association to different owner objects in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, polymorphic-associations

is it possible to use kind of polymorphic association to different **owner** objects in Doctrine 2? I mean that for example ImageGroup entity is owned by different entities: Article, Album, Post, Comment, etc. So there should be "ownerId" and "ownerType" attributes in ImageGroup table, where "ownerType" is discriminator.

I am already using **[Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)** and also **[Superclass mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)** on other object relationships in my project, but any of them suits for this problem, if I am correct. Because in these situations referred objects are inherited.

I have read answers to polymorphic associations here, but I found no answer to my example.

In my example is no inheritance at all. Any help, please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [strategy pattern](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/strategy-cookbook-introduction.html), which basically allows you to have a weak link between your objects and the ones you want to reference, such as `['name' => 'EntityName', 'identifier' => 123]`.